# You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to contact_info without a defaultt

Tags: python, django

I am using the command python manage.py makemigrations

However, I get this error:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'id' to contact_info
> without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to
> populate existing rows).  Please select a fix:  1) Provide a one-off
> default now (will be set on all existing rows)  2) Quit, and let me
> add a default in models.py

Here is models.py:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    post_uesr = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True,related_name='create_user')
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    post_description = models.TextField(max_length=800, null=True, blank=True)
    post_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    post_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.post_uesr}'
```

Comment: that is not an error!! it is a prompt asking to select any option (1 or 2)

Comment: maybe you need not null=True, but nullable=True?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a bug, it's documented and logical. You add a new field, which is (by best practice, as you noticed) not NULLable so django has to put something into it for the existing records .

You can press 1 so this option applies

```
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)
```

so just press 1, if thats your case as value.
else if you want to abort this task and provide manually press 2 and this option applies.

```
 2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
```

BUT here in your case **id** is a default field already included in every table you create and that will be default to primary key.

And if you are looking to add another AutoField probably this will help

```
order = models.AutoField(primary_key=False)
```

And if you are trying to make primary key as uuid4 format

```
import uuid
id = models.AutoField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

it's telling you should specified a default value for your id field.

ask you for adding manually a default value to this field or make a field without any default value in database.

for example for using UUID as your post id you should do like this:

```
import uuid

from django.db import models

class Posts(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    # other lines of codes
```

and this is because you are using an AutoField.
you can change it like this:

```
import uuid
from django.db import models

class Posts(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
    # other lines of codes
```

Comment: please describe your answer in a more correct and expressive way using descriptive variables

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).